# JavaScript on Vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm having some issue with JavaScript on Vscode, for some reason my curly braces doesn't automatically insert an empty line in middle when pressing Enter, but is stuck with second line

```js
function myFunction(a, b) { 
    /*when I pressed enter here, cursor should be automatically here */
}
```

Instead, my Vscode is doing this

```js
function myFunction(a, b) { 
    /* when I pressed Enter, it skipped one line like this */
}
```

Comment: perhaps you haven't installed the right extensions, or disabled something, or ... the reasons are many - has it ever worked like you want? What did you do to break it?

Comment: I wanted to see if i can skip one line for curly braces, and yes it has worked before
When I changed some settings it somehow doesn't work and now even tho i have these settings resetted it still doesn't work

Comment: Well, you changed "something" - the solution is usually to "change it back" - you say you did, but your current situation suggests otherwise

Comment: nvm i freaking found it, i just simply delete every settings in the .json file and redo, and now it works. I am never touching that setting ever again

Comment: I was just about to suggest deleting the `.vscode/settings.json` in the project :p

Comment: check if you've disabled any builtin extensions. search `@builtin` in the Extensions View.

Comment: @NguyenKhoiPhan the response should not be "i don't understand, i'm never attempting again." if anything you learned when something goes wrong, you can always reset the settings to restore the original behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution may help you

1. Go to File > Preferences > Settings.
2. In the search bar, type
   `javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions`.
3. Check the box next to the option
   `javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions`.
4. Repeat steps 3 and 4 for the option
   `javascript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForControlBlocks`.
5. Save the changes.

This should fix the issue and allow you to insert an empty line in between curly braces when pressing Enter. If you’re still facing issues, please let me know.
I hope I helped you

Comment: you don't need to save the changes made in the Settings GUI

Comment: correct @rioV8 I just forgot